# Java Swing: How to remove the default-spacing for JButtons in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, spacing, flowlayout

I'm busy writing a button menu for a Java Swing application and I am wondering if it is possible to remove the padding between `JButton`s that are added to a JPanel.

The `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` that is aligned left.

```
JPanel panelMenu = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
```

The buttons are standard `JButton`s

```
JButton buttOne = new JButton("One");
JButton buttTwo = new JButton("Two");
```

I added the JButtons to the panel as normal

```
add(panelMenu, BorderLayout.NORTH);
panelMenu.add(buttOne);
panelMenu.add(buttTwo);
```

Everything works as expected but what do I need to do to remove the default spacing between the buttons?

I found a suggested solution online which is the following

```
buttOne.setBorder(null);
buttOne.setBorderPainted(false);
buttOne.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));

buttTwo.setBorder(null);
buttTwo.setBorderPainted(false);
buttTwo.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
```

However this seems to remove the spacing inside of the button and not the spacing between each button.

Is this spacing produced by the `FlowLayout`? If so, how can I remove it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`// 0, 0` equates to horizontal and vertical offsets, the default is 5.

```
JPanel panelMenu = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 0, 0));
```

Should sort it!

Answer (score 3):

The `FlowLayout` controls the spacing, the default is 5.
Use `new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 0)` to remove the spacing.